# Ubuntu 20.04/gnome wifi and bluetooth in Settings

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, gui, 64-bit

Pi4 4Gb with Ubuntu 20.04 64b (flashed from Raspberry Pi Imager). Added minimal gnome after the install. When I go to Settings:

- Bluetooth says: "No Bluetooth installed. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth"
- Wifi settings has a spinner and an empty box titled "Visible Networks". The box never populates.

Well shucks. We all know the Pi has perfectly good Bluetooth. And I set up Wifi before the first boot using netplan. I'm accessing my home network and the internet just fine over wifi. So this would appear to be an issue with gnome, right?

I am NOT asking for help getting wifi or Bluetooth working. This is about the GUI.

I don't really need to "fix" wifi, but I'm curious about why the Settings app doesn't work. And I'm sure I can find out how to use the terminal to do anything necessary with Bluetooth, but again, I'm just curious about what's going on with gnome. Can anyone help me connect the dots? Thanks!

Comment: Canonical, in its infinite wisdom, doesn't have a supported Pi Desktop OS and uses different networking, kernel and many other packages.
It lacks support for some of the Pi hardware, although it does work as a server.

Comment: Thanks @Milliways. Cannonical claims certification of 20.04 on the Pi. Maybe I'll try installing one of the GUIs they recommend on their Pi page. If I had paid more attention while apt installing my current desktop, would I have seen error messages indicating there would be problems?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156466/cannot-find-bluetooth-device-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-3-b

Running the following command (twice!) eventually started Bluetooth:

```
sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 -
```

For troubleshooting see also

```
dmesg | grep bluetooth
```

Mine shows a bunch of warnings like `apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez"` but after `hciattach` it seems to work, at least until the next power cycle.